# A regular expression that matches two long strings and ignores everything in between

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am searching through a 1.5 million line Premiere Pro project for any text that matches one of my audio filters and is set to mono. 
Text that I am searching for begins with the `<ChannelType>` tag and ends with the `<FilterMatchName>`Tags. So it would looks like this

```
<ChannelType>0</ChannelType>
            <FrameRate>5292000</FrameRate>
        </AudioComponent>
        <FilterPreset>0</FilterPreset>
        <OpaqueData Encoding="base64" Checksum="53060659">AAAAAD8L8lo+AUr+Pac1NjwTmoUAAAAAP0uQDD37nIg9ui6MPjwU5j+AAAA+C/JaAAAAAD8qqqsAAAAAP4AAAD92L8w9py8FAAAAAHNvZnQgY29tcHJlc3Npb24AIiBkZWZhdWx0PSIwIiBzdGVwPSIxIiBtaW49IjAiIG1heD0iMSIvPgoJICA8Zmw=</OpaqueData>
        <FilterIndex>-1</FilterIndex>
        <FilterMatchName>1094998321 Dynamics1</FilterMatchName>
```

If I were in a Word doc, I would just do a find as

```
<ChannelType>0</ChannelType>*<FilterMatchName>1094998321 Dynamics1</FilterMatchName>
```

I am terrible with Regex. I was hoping someone could help me out. Everything I have tried either doesn't match anything, or matches EVERYTHING in the document. I am using Notepad++.

Comment: You are trying to use regex for something that really should be XSLT

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working in Notepad++, you have access to `PCRE` regular expressions. This one will get all the text between `<ChannelType>` and `</FilterMatchName>`

```
(?s)<ChannelType>.*?</FilterMatchName>
```

- the `(?s)` allows the `.` to match newline characters
- After matching `<ChannelType>`, the `.*?` lazily matches all characters up to...
- the closing `</FilterMatchName>`, which we match.

Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

What type of regular expressions are you using (which language/library)?
Basically you can use `.*` instead of `*` in regular expressions. IF your text is long though, it's better to use a `Reluctant` quantifier[1] if your re implementation allows it.

This is a good site with comparison of different re implementations and tutorials:
http://www.regular-expressions.info

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: What out about .* it is short form for [^\n] (UNIX applications) or [^\r\n] (Windows applications).

Comment: @Fede, no, it matches all characters. But many programs match line by line so new lines are not matched. You can usually control that with flags. I see op updated question after my answer or I didn't notice he's talking about notepad++ and he got an answer about it already.